# Get substring in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have variables which represent email subject with these strings:

```
Snap: Processor
 'ir.basisswap-1702|sydney-ir.basisswap-ricsxml-location_mapping' for
 '20181231' failed [Production2]
```

and `Snap: 'ir.broker.caplet.vol' RBS data valucheck failed [production]`

**Desired output:**

I want to get values between `Snap:` and failed

`Processor 'ir.basisswap-1702|sydney-ir.basisswap-ricsxml-location_mapping' for '20181231'` and `'ir.broker.caplet.vol' RBS data valucheck`

```
regex1 = r'Snap:\s*(\S+)'
          a=re.findall(regex1 ,mail["Subject"])
```

**Actual output:**

`Processor` for first and `ir.broker.caplet.vol` for second

Comment: You're capturing only things up to (not including) the next space. I don't have a proper keyboard to answer properly but perhaps that will get you going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\S+` only matches a sequence of non-whitespace characters, so the match ends at the next space.

You want to match until the word `failed`, so use:

```
regex1 = r'Snap:\s*(.+?)\s+failed'
```

You need to use a non-greedy `+?` quantifier so that it only matches up to the first `failed`.

If the subjects contain newline characters, you should also use the `re.DOTALL` flag so that `.` will match newline.